# In Cloud Firestore how to get all item that respect some condition in childs

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this database structure in Cloud Firestore of Firebase:

```
{
  "Club": [
    {
      "name": "club one",
      "address": "via Roma",
      "owners": [
        {
          "name": "Mario Rossi",
          "id": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Giorgio Verdi",
          "id": "2",
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "club two",
      "address": "via milano",
      "owners": [
        {
          "name": "Giorgio Verdi",
          "id": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to retrieve in Swift 4 all clubs that have owner with id = 2.

This code does not work for me:

```
let citiesRef = db.collection("clubs")
.whereField( "owners", arrayContains: 2)
.getDocuments()
```

This is the real database structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to query for that in your current structure. You'll want to keep a separate array of owner IDs to allow this query:

```
  "owner-ids": [ "1", "2" ],
  "owners": [
    {
      "name": "Mario Rossi",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Giorgio Verdi",
      "id": "2",
    }
  ]
```

Now you can use `array-contains` on the `owner-ids` array.